# How to run your project without hash in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-routing

I have an Angular project which is running for almost 4 years and in this project we used **hash(#)** in the routing part, now for some reason the **hash(#)** needs to be removed.

In this part, I removed the config `useHash` that I had previously given to routing
[image]

Now my project works as expected without # and there is no problem, and it also moves between the links correctly

But as soon as my page is refreshed, no page comes up and no request goes to the server, only a series of errors appear in the console and NetWork.

netWork errors : [image]

console errors : [image]

Comment: please validate the `<base href="/">` in `index.html`,

Comment: @NarenMurali Answer the question, I confirm and upvote, and do you think this title is good for this question?

Comment: Thanks much! Yes its great, hope it helps someone in the future!

Comment: Questions here cannot depend on screenshots of text. Please edit your question to include your code as actually copy-pastabke text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your network tab in localhost is having errors for the js files its usually due to the base href in the `index.html` not being set properly, could you try setting the tag as.

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularTourOfHeroes</title>
  <base href="/"> <!-- this line should be set, you can ignore the others here -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
```